# Cannot convert from SQL type 93 to C type 8

Tags: oracle, ssis-2017

I AM using Oracle datasource in my ETL package which uses SQL command as data Access mode. Unfortunately i AM getting error

> Cannot convert from SQL type 93 to C type 8

I know that query used in Oracle datasource doesn't return any values. How should i update query to be able to do conversion?
Query is very Simple

```
Select Data from MyTable
```

Regards

Comment: Show the create table for the source - may be some weird datatype